# cmake project build error, shared library with a dependency on another

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm building a project that uses cmake.

The project uses three shared libraries .so files.

In the CMakeLists.txt file I've added the these lines which link the shared libraries to the executable.

```
project (lwm2mclient)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/mraa-master-built/build/src)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/libi2capi)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/libtca6424a)
target_link_libraries (lwm2mclient libmraa.so m libi2capi.so libtca6424a.so)
```

However, one of the shared libraries `libtca6424a.so`depends on `libi2capi.so` i.e. it uses methods that are defined in it.

So when I'm building the cmake project I get an error like this saying that the `.so` file cannot find the method which is defined in the other `.so` file `libtca6424a.so`.

Could somebody suggest a solution?

```
/../../lib/libtca6424a.so: undefined reference to `i2c_write_byte_data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
target_link_libraries (-Wl,--start-group lwm2mclient libmraa.so m libi2capi.so libtca6424a.so -Wl,--end-group)
```

or change the order of the libraries